# How to access Kafka consumer metrics (consumer-fetch-manager-metrics) using JmxTool?

Tags: apache-kafka, jmx

I use kafka_2.12-2.1.0.

The command I'm using:

```
bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.JmxTool \
  --object-name 'kafka.consumer:type=consumer-fetch-manager-metrics,client-id=([-.\w]+)'
  --jmx-url service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:9999/jmxrmi
```

The error I'm getting:

```
Trying to connect to JMX url: service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:9999/jmxrmi.
No matched attributes for the queried objects ArrayBuffer(kafka.consumer:type=consumer-fetch-manager-metrics,client-id=([-.w]+)).
```

I am able to get other metrics except this consumer lag.

Answer (score 1):

`service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:9999/jmxrmi` is the default remote JMX URL and could simply point to a Kafka broker not a Kafka consumer.

In other words, make sure you use a proper `--jmx-url` URL to connect to the Kafka consumer.

Use `jps` or `jcmd` command-line tools to know the proper value.